# Improper integral $\int\limits_0^{+ \infty }\frac{e^x \mathbb{arctg}(xe^{-x})}{(x+ \sqrt[3]{x})^ \alpha }dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I need help  to find all $\alpha$ that
$\int\limits_0^{+ \infty }\frac{e^x \mathbb{arctg}(xe^{-x})}{(x+ \sqrt[3]{x})^ \alpha }dx$ converges.

I tried Dirichlet's test. Or should I use Taylor expansion?

Comment: Just observe the leading behaviour of the integrand at $\infty$ which is $$\sim \frac{x}{(x+x^{1/3})^{\alpha}} \sim x^{1-\alpha} \,. $$

Comment: Thank you for your respond.

Comment: @Diger: How do you get $\ x$ in the numerator?

Comment: @AntonS Use the fact that $\arctan(t) \sim t$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: @AntonS Similarly, the integrand behaves like $x^{1 - \alpha /3}$ as $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: the result is strange: $\alpha > 2$ and $\alpha > 6$ since the $x^{ \alpha}$ converges if $\alpha < -1$.

Comment: How do you figure $\alpha>6$?

Comment: from $1 - \alpha /3 < -1$

Comment: the answer is $ \alpha<6$ and $\alpha<2$. I forgot to present this integral as a sum of two integrals

Comment: It's $2<\alpha<6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all, *Welcome to the site !*

Consider
$$f(x)=e^x \tan ^{-1}\left(x \,e^{-x} \right)$$ When $x$ is small

$$x \,e^{-x}= x-x^2+\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{x^4}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(x \,e^{-x}\right)=x-x^2+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{5 x^4}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$e^x\tan ^{-1}\left(x \,e^{-x}\right)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^4}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)$$

When $x$ is large use
$$\tan^{-1}(t)=t-\frac{t^3}{3}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ Let $t=x e^{-x}$
$$\tan^{-1}(x e^{-x})=x e^{-x}-\frac{1}{3}x^3 e^{-3 x} +\cdots$$
$$e^x\tan^{-1}(x e^{-x})=x -\frac{1}{3}x^3 e^{-2 x} +\cdots$$ So, at both ends

$$f(x) \sim x$$ Jus to convince you, plot $f(x)$ for $0\leq x \leq 1000$

So, as @Diger already commented, the problem is almost the same as
$$\int_0^\infty \frac x {\left(x+\sqrt[3]{x}\right)^{\alpha }}\,dx$$ Use now an obvious substitution and the problem becomes simple.

Comment: thank you Claude for your help

Comment: @AntonS. You are very welcome ! When you will finish, I suggest you post the solution and I shall show you .... something. Cheers :-)